# Filter MySQL query on difference between timestamp fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like:

```
 RCD_ID      ID           TIMESTAMP
--------|-----------|---------------------
    1,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:19:17'
    3,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:22:46'
    4,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:24:36'
    5,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:29:49'
    7,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:40:02'
    9,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 17:11:55'
```

And I need to filter the result set so each records has a 'distance' of 20 minutes each other:

```
 RCD_ID      ID          TIMESTAMP
--------|-----------|---------------------
    1,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:19:17'
    7,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 16:40:02'
    9,   2737738826, '2015-10-30 17:11:55'
```

[*WRONG QUESTION: Which is the best (and fastest) way to do it?*]

RIGHT QUESTION: Could someone give me some suggestion how to start from?

**EDIT**

I added a record_id field to the table, I try this query:

```
select m.*,
       (select m2.rcd_id 
        from tbl_data m2 
        where (m2.rcd_id > m.rcd_id) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, m.log_timestamp, m2.log_timestamp) >= 30)
        order by m2.rcd_id limit 1) as m2
from tbl_data as m
```

But it returns all the records. Am I on the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried nothing useful until now because I don't know how to figure out.

Comment: You have no knowledge of what you're asking, you haven't tried anything and not willing to either - you just want other people to write your code for you? If you can't be bothered to try something yourself or post your research, then nobody will bother helping you. If you seriously have no SQL knowledge, enough to make a working/not working query, my advice is to hire a professional and/or learn more first. You can't just come to SO and have SQL queries built to your specification.

Comment: No, I don't just want people write code for me. I'm only asking a suggestion where to start from, nothing more. If I was been an SQL expert I would not have needed to ask.
I thinks SO is a place where knowledge could be shared, not only between experts. But, nevermind..

Comment: @Barzo: **"Which is the best (and fastest) way to do it?"** is not asking a suggestion where to start from - you're asking for the best and fastest query to get your desired results. Maybe a forum would be a better place to ask suggestions. Do some quick Google research on "selecting records with timestamp difference greater than X minutes", try and come up with a query that you can share here with us and we'll help to get it working.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid ok, I was wrong to write my question, sorry. So, if now I change to "could someone give me some suggestion how to start from" could be better?

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at joining the table (I've used the name 'logs') to itself and only keeping those records that meet your time constraint, something like:

`SELECT * FROM logs AS t1, logs AS t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.TIMESTAMP != t2.TIMESTAMP AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIMESTAMP, t2.TIMESTAMP) = 20`

Comment: @Barzo: a message popped up from you, saying it was what you wanted, but it then disappeared. If the answer does do what you want, feel free to accept it!

Comment: Hi @nick, maybe there was some problem saving my reply. First of all, thanks for you suggestion. I try you query but it does not fill what I need. I edit my post to try explain better what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi @Barzo. I was using the app for the first time and it seems to delete notifications rather than display them! I've realised my mistake in my first attempt. I'd missed out the "and t1.timestamp != t2.timestamp" clause. I've run it on a data table with a timestamp and it works now! The full query is in the edited answer.

Comment: Having read your edited question, your attempt looks to be massively complicated for the task you appear to be describing. Have another look at my query - check the '= 20' bit. I wasn't sure what you meant by 'distance'. Do you mean at least 20 minutes apart? If so, put >= 20 instead.

Comment: Hi @nick, first of all thanks for the replies. Maybe I misunderstood something because I cannot get it right.  When I run your query, the interval seems to be "calculated" only for the first row (the first row it return is 20 minute later then the table first row) but the other rows are retrieved as it appear in the original table.  Also if I use ">= 20" (which is what I need) it return duplicates rows.  Maybe I'm wrong but I think here a sort of "JOIN" or "Sub Query" is needed.

Comment: Hi. I don't have an exactly similar data table to test this on. If there are several records with the same id, then the first one will match will all those that are more than 20 mins afterwards. Try putting the TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIMESTAMP, t2.TIMESTAMP) AS aDelay  as a field in the SELECT. Try also using MAX() to identify the longest delay or maybe DISTINCT. You can restrict using HAVING aDelay >= 20.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions #nick. 
After some tests I think that what I need is quite impossible with a simple query because my requirement is recursive:

1-> find the next row with tdiff>=20 mins on some order 
2-> starting with that row, do it again 
3-> until there are no more rows 

So I think I need to write a Stored Procedure